# RealPlayer like Android app layout

Tags: android-layout

I am new to Android and I am trying to design my Android application like the interface of the Android RealPlayer but I have no idea how!

What I exactly want to design is: Break the page into 4 equal grid-like sections such that the whole page is covered and no extra empty space is left at the end of the page (exactly like the RealPlayer interface).

[image: Real Player Interface]

[image: My app]

```
<?xml version="l.0" encoding="utf—8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android“
    android:id=“@+id/gridview“
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="l.0"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="l0dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:stretchMode=“columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="l0dp" >

</GridView>
```

I have tried manipulating `GridView` attributes but it seems that it is not possible only using `GridView` elements. I hope my problem statement is clear enough! Can somebody give me a hint on how to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found out that it is possible using buttons of different sizes!